# Unable to retrieve the custom fields when Docusign Connect calls listener

Tags: docusignapi

I sent few custom fields to docusign through API with document to be signed. When document got completed and docusign conenct hit my callback listener for passing event, I do not find the custom fields in that. My request looks like:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">  
    <emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject> 
    <status>sent</status> 
    <documents>
        <document> 
            <documentId>1</documentId> 
            <name> <DOCUMENT_NAME> </name> 
        </document> 
    </documents>
    <recipients> 
        <signers> 
            <signer> 
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>    
                <name> <RECIPIENT_NAME> </name>
                <email> <RECIPIENT_EMAIL> </email>                              
            </signer> 
        </signers> 
    </recipients>  
    <customFields> 
        <customField> 
            <name>callingApp</name>
            <show>false</show>
            <required>true</required>
            <value>DMS</value>
            <customFieldType>text</customFieldType>
        </customField> 
    </customFields>  
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your connect listener you want to enable `Include Document Fields`.

If you were doing an Envelope based Event Notification (connect event), it would be different.